# Much higher LLM training loss when gradients are accumulated in FP32

Tags: deep-learning, gradient, gradient-clipping

I'm training a large language model in BF16 precision. The model architecture is the same as llama v1. I'm using [Megatron-LM](https://github.com/NVIDIA/Megatron-LM) (along with my own integration of [DeepSpeed](https://github.com/microsoft/DeepSpeed/)) as the main training software.

I have done some training tests, basic training seems to be fine, but one particular training behavior really makes me scratching my head:

1. If gradients are accumulated in **BF16**, and gradient clipping is **disabled**, everything is fine, loss spikes occasionally.

   - normal behavior for large language model training.
2. If gradients are accumulated in **BF16**, and gradient clipping is **enabled**, training is unstable, loss spikes quite often.

   - this is expected, since complicated calculations on low precision numbers are likely to cause training stability issues.
3. If gradients are accumulated in **FP32**, and gradient clipping is **enabled**, training is stable, **but the training loss is much higher** (2.4 vs 2.0).

Why gradient accumulation in higher precision will cause training loss to be higher (slower model convergence) ?

This is very unintuitive, since higher precision equals more accurate calculation, equals more accurate gradient direction, (intuitively) equals faster model convergence.